# RateLimited requests auto-retrying

Tags: resilience4j

I'm upgrading my project from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3. We were making use of **io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2** in Spring boot 2, because of the upgrade, I moved it to **io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot3** and few of the test cases have started failing.

this is my ratelimiter config.

```
resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  instances:
    service1:
      limit-for-period: 10
      limit-refresh-period: 1s
      timeout-duration: 0
```

This is my test case that is failing.

```
final RateLimiter serviceRateLimiter = registry.rateLimiter("service1");
final RateLimiterConfig config = esRateLimiter.getRateLimiterConfig();
serviceRateLimiter.changeLimitForPeriod(1);
serviceRateLimiter.changeTimeoutDuration(Duration.ZERO);
final List<HttpStatusCode> concurrentResponses = IntStream.range(0, 3).parallel().mapToObj(
                        (__) -> {
                            try {
                                ResponseEntity<> response =  execute(request);
                                return response;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
            ).map(ResponseEntity::getStatusCode).collect(toList());
assertThat(concurrentResponses).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(OK, TOO_MANY_REQUESTS, TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
```

The expectation is that since we're setting only 1 request to go through in 1 second, we should get two rate limited requests. I can see from the logs that the requests are getting rate limited but for some reason they are getting retried on their own and eventually one of those requests succeed.

Any idea on this behaviour?

I thought it had something to do with retry configuration of Resilience4J but that is not the case.